# Using Scikit Learn, model was optimized for precision using refit, yet recall is much higher

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, random-forest

Working on the Indian Liver Patient Dataset from UCI (http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/ILPD+%28Indian+Liver+Patient+Dataset%29), I trained 2 models, RF and SVM, to predict a binary label.

I tried optimizing it in both cases for precision as a metric using refit within RandomizedSearchCV but each time recall was much higher (for RF 76.5 vs 97%, for SVM 78% vs 100%). I'm wondering if there's anything I've done wrong, or that you sometimes just cannot improve certain metrics beyond a certain point.

```
    def randomized_search_wrapper(pipeline, ranking=0, iterations=100, cores=-1, refit_score='precision_score'):
    """
    Fits a RandomizedSearchCV classifier using refit_score for
    optimization, prints classifier performance metrics"""

    randomized_search = RandomizedSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid, cv=10,  
                               refit=refit_score, scoring=scorers, return_train_score=True, 
                               n_iter=iterations, random_state=42, verbose=0, n_jobs=cores)

    randomized_search.fit(X_train, y_train)


    print(f'Best params for {refit_score}')
    print(randomized_search.best_params_)


    return randomized_search
```

The scorers used:

```
scorers = {
    'accuracy_score': make_scorer(accuracy_score),
    'precision_score': make_scorer(precision_score),
    'recall_score': make_scorer(recall_score),
    'f1_score': make_scorer(f1_score),
    'roc_auc_score': make_scorer(roc_auc_score)
}
```

Comment: Please update your post to show your `scorers` variable.

Comment: Well, "*that you sometimes just cannot improve certain metrics beyond a certain point*" goes without saying (I would say *most* of the times)! There does not seem to be any issue with your code and your results are not unexpected.